# Is it possible to configure a Consul health check that can be set to critical, but defaults to healthy after a TTL?

Tags: consul

My main goal is to avoid a big delay in the health status updating to "Critical" when I can predict my service will go down.
I would combine this with the http health check already in place.

Considered solutions:

- I have tried a TTL check, but this introduces the burden of converting the service to constantly send it's current status.
- Using a TTL check with a really high ttl + sending "healthy" once on restart came to mind, but if this initial request fails the service stays unhealthy way too long.
- Reducing the interval of my http health-check would mitigate the problem a bit, but also creates a bigger overhead.

Comment: I have requested a feature enabling this, but it seems to have been closed.
https://github.com/hashicorp/consul/issues/5976

Answer (score 3):

If you can predict the service will go down, you should consider putting it into maintenance mode. This will remove it from DNS and API results immediately. [Here is the link to the documentation](https://www.consul.io/api/agent/service.html#enable-maintenance-mode) on how to put service into the maintenance mode.

Health checks will always have a delay, since they are executed periodically and are designed to monitor service for unexpected downtime. Best way to have minimal impact on users, if you know service is going down due to update/upgrade/reboot/decomissioning, is to remove it before doing any work on it.

Comment: After testing: the service stays in maintenance mode after restarting.
The problem of the service being down too long if removing the maintenance flag fails still persists.
This is only a slight improvement over my second proposal.

Comment: @Wouter did you try calling maintenance API and setting the parameter `enable=false` after you have successfully restarted your service? Here is the example from the documentation, I have modified it to have `enable=false` : `curl --request PUT http://127.0.0.1:8500/v1/agent/service/maintenance/my-service-id?enable=fasle&reason=after+restart`  or if you have `consul` command line configured `consul maint -disable -service=<your-service-id>`

Comment: Yes, I am aware I can set the maintenance flag to enable=false.
My issue is that if this request fails, manually re-sending the request is necessary, or the service stays down indefinitely.